# neo4j finding a node to create a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

neo4j is neo4j community edition, version 3.1.1

I create a node for a LUN

```
merge ( l3:lun {nom:"OS_SU1_", serie:"123456", coordonnees:"00:00:00"})
set l3.taille = 102400
```

latter on, I want to connect a host to this LUN, creating host is easy

```
 merge (hSUP_1:host {nom:"SUP_1"})
```

now the big deal, I want to find l by its coordinate and create the relationship, I tried

```
match (l:lun {coordonnees : "00:00:00"}) merge (hSUP_1) -[:connecte_a]-> (l)
```

and get an error:

> WITH is required between MERGE and MATCH (line ...)

(I cannot keep `l3` identifier above, those lines are generated by a script that parse different file)

what is correct syntax ?

man page searched : neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/ (3.3.8.4. Merge relationships )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yop,

You can't make a MATCH after a MERGE,so you have to add a WITH between like this :

```
MERGE (hSUP_1:host {nom:"SUP_1"})
MATCH (l:lun {coordonnees : "00:00:00"}) 
WITH l, hSUP
  MERGE (hSUP_1) -[:connecte_a]-> (l)
```

Otherwise, you can also change the order like this :

```
MATCH (l:lun {coordonnees : "00:00:00"}) 
MERGE (hSUP_1:host {nom:"SUP_1"})
MERGE (hSUP_1) -[:connecte_a]-> (l)
```

Comment: Second solution work, however I cannot insert more than one host. I am using the browser (localhost:7474).

Comment: I don't understand  'inserting more than one host' ... What do you mean by this ?

Comment: using the browser option, it seems that "statement1 ; statement2" will fail. skipping semicolon would result in MERGE and MATCH being mixed the wrong way. (I figure out how to run cypher-shell, it is not worth asking a new fuzzy question)

Comment: You can only do one statement in the browser. To batch some statements, you should use the `cypher-shell` (like you said)